# php preg_match_all and recursive rexep

Tags: php, regex

I have some trouble with a generated file, and I like to make some substitution

Say I have got this pattern :

```
<ul/><htmlelement>some text</htmlelement>
```

I want to find with my regexep the value of some text, since I can find the element htmlelement with a regexp, i want to recursively include it in the regex like

```
preg_match_all("#<ul/><([^><])>(.)*</(first capuring match)>#", $string, $matches);
```

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

1. You miss the `+` quantifier for the "htmlelement" opening tag.
2. You need the `*` inside the capture group
3. and better make it non-greedy with `?`.
4. Refer the "first capturing match" with `\1`.

So the regex should be:

```
<ul\/><([^><]+)>(.*?)<\/\1>
             ^    ^^     ^
             1    23     4
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/f25N9J/1

Comment: Thank you for your help, in the second capturing parenthesis, I would like also to avoid to have the </1> string ...so something lik </ul><[^><+]>(everything that is not containing </\1>)</\1> ( the escape \/ is not necessary in my php regex ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the point avoiding the </1> in the second capture group. Could you please provide a data sample and expected result?

Comment: <ul/><htmlelement>some text</htmlelement> bla </htmlelement>, I want the regex to capure some text, but not some text </htmlelement> bla ...

Comment: This regex does so: https://regex101.com/r/f25N9J/2. That's why the non-greedy `?` (point 3) is required.